# how to report master connection status in android

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working on an android application which connects a master on PC.
I wonder if there's any way to feedback the current connection status in android user interface ? I can see the status in logcat in eclipse, but is there a way to show it to the android user?

one of the idea is to catch the registration error, and make a toast to handle it. is it possible to catch the registration error? if yes, where to catch it?

following is the logcat from eclipse. i want to tell the user "connecting to master failed" whenever the following error occurs.

```
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158): Exception caught while communicating with master.
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: orome.intern.vmi.ei.tum.de/192.168.13.7:11311 - Connection refused
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientFactory$1.invoke(XmlRpcClientFactory.java:157)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at $Proxy0.unregisterPublisher(Native Method)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.ros.internal.node.client.MasterClient.unregisterPublisher(MasterClient.java:161)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar$3$1.call(Registrar.java:170)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar$3$1.call(Registrar.java:167)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar.callMaster(Registrar.java:111)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar.access$100(Registrar.java:51)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar$3.call(Registrar.java:167)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar$3.call(Registrar.java:164)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: orome.intern.vmi.ei.tum.de/192.168.13.7:11311 - Connection refused
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport.writeRequest(XmlRpcCommonsTransport.java:227)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:151)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker$1.run(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:80)
04-17 12:16:50.856: E/Registrar(17158):     ... 1 more
04-17 12:16:50.866: I/DefaultPublisher(17158): Publisher unregistration failed: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeSlaveIdentifier</Ant_Sender, http://192.168.13.111:43461>, TopicIdentifier</ANT>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</ANT>, TopicDescription<ant_msgs/sdm,c5bc5cc934c24b6f16ba7e243086fdbb>>>>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31880/how-to-report-master-connection-status-in-android/) by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-16**:
Master connections are not maintained. The go up and down as necessary. What exactly do you want to report to the user? Do you want to ping the master to see if it's alive?

**Comment by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on 2012-04-17**:
ping master could also be an idea thx for that! how can i do it?
i wanted to catch the error above and make a toast to the user. but i don't know where to catch this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps you're looking for the PublisherListener API. See:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/javadoc/org/ros/node/topic/Publisher.html#addListener(org.ros.node.topic.PublisherListener)
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/javadoc/org/ros/internal/node/RegistrantListener.html#onMasterRegistrationFailure(T)

There is an example provided in the documentation here:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/advanced.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on 2012-04-19**:
thx! i think the second one is what I'm looking for. any idea where i should implement it? in my nodemain?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-19**:
That's a good place, yes. Wherever you call newPublisher().

**Comment by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on 2012-04-19**:
thank you Damon  Kohler. just another stupic question, what should the parameter be? somehow i can't figure out what type my registrant is. also shall i instantiate a new registrantlistener or there's any method to create a new one (like messagefactory)

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-22**:
See the example I linked to above. I just pushed it, so it may take a few minutes to show up.

**Comment by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on 2012-04-24**:
this is really helpful. thx a lot!

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2016-10-21**:
Hi, dead link in your answer, should be https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/blob/master/docs/src/main/sphinx/advanced.rst

**Comment by [Tav_PG](https://answers.ros.org/users/43825/tav_pg/) on 2019-09-11**:
All the above links are now dead.  Does anyone know where they have moved to?